# why can't I validate this xml against this xsd?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I can't seem to validate http://pastebin.com/jbFzRuUD against http://pastebin.com/cgvTdVWA

Here are the errors I get :

```
  /schema-check xml.xml xsd.xsd 
    Error at file "/stuff/xml.xml", line 3, column 63
     Message: Unknown element 'dcst:SubtitleReel'
    Error at file "/stuff/xml.xml", line 3, column 63
     Message: Attribute '{http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/}dcst' is not declared for element 'dcst:SubtitleReel'
    Error at file "/stuff/xml.xml", line 4, column 12
     Message: Unknown element 'dcst:Id'
    Error at file "/stuff/xml.xml", line 5, column 26
     Message: Unknown element 'dcst:ContentTitleText'
    Error at file "/stuff/xml.xml", line 6, column 24
     Message: Unknown element 'dcst:AnnotationText'
    Error at file "/stuff/xml.xml", line 8, column 46
     Message: Unknown element 'xs:IssueDate'
    Error at file "/stuff/xml.xml", line 8, column 46
     Message: Attribute '{http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/}xs' is not declared for element 'xs:IssueDate'
    Fatal Error at file "/stuff/xml.xml", line 9, column 18
     Message: The prefix 'xs' has not been mapped to any URI
```

I have some experience on xml, less on namespace though I've done my homework and read quite a bit on namespaces on w3 site and xml validation, without finding what was wrong.

I would appreciate any help, this is to build a free online tool bit.ly/isqd4a

I've used online tools to validate, and also shema-check from Apache xml security software

tia

Comment: When asking questions on SO, please include specific information.  "It doesn't work" cannot be resolved without some explanation of the specific problem (i.e. what error) you are seeing.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a IDE like eclipse, intellij or XMLSpy to debug XSD and XML. [Kernow](http://kernowforsaxon.sourceforge.net/) is also good

If you validate the XML in such a tool you get errors such as

> Line 7, Col 18 The prefix "xs" for element "xs:ReelNumber" is not bound.

That particular error means that it cant find ReelNumber within the xs namespace, you should be using the dcst namespace.... and so forth

targetNamespace in XSD is "http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/428-7/2010/DCST"

the XML instance points to dcst="http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/428-7/2007/DCST

Comment: thank you very much. Indeed the main error was that there were slight differences in the URI of the namespaces. After that, with minor modifications I could make the xml validate. Problem solved